# Uno User Hand, Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to code the user's hand.

How would I get the user to attain 7 random cards from the list I've created, this is what I have so far:

```
deck_red=['Red:0','Red:1','Red:1','Red:2','Red:2','Red:3',
            'Red:3','Red:4','Red:4','Red:5','Red:5','Red:6',
            'Red:6','Red:7','Red:7','Red:8','Red:8','Red:9',
            'Red:9','Red:+2','Red:+2','Red:Skip','Red:Skip',]


deck_blue=['Blue:0','Blue:1','Blue:1','Blue:2','Blue:2','Blue:3',
           'Blue:3','Blue:4','Blue:4','Blue:5','Blue:5','Blue:6',
           'Blue:6','Blue:7','Blue:7','Blue:8','Blue:8','Blue:9',
           'Blue:9','Blue:+2','Blue:+2','Blue:Skip','Blue:Skip',]


deck_yellow=['Yellow:0','Yellow:1','Yellow:1','Yellow:2','Yellow:2','Yellow:3',
           'Yellow:3','Yellow:4','Yellow:4','Yellow:5','Yellow:5','Yellow:6',
           'Yellow:6','Yellow:7','Yellow:7','Yellow:8','Yellow:8','Yellow:9',
           'Yellow:9','Yellow:+2','Yellow:+2','Yellow:Skip','Yellow:Skip',]


deck_green=['Green:0','Green:1','Green:1','Green:2','Green:2','Green:3',
           'Green:3','Green:4','Green:4','Green:5','Green:5','Green:6',
           'Green:6','Green:7','Green:7','Green:8','Green:8','Green:9',
           'Green:9','Green:+2','Green:+2','Green:Skip','Green:Skip',]


wild_cards=['Wild','Wild','Wild','Wild',
            'Wild+4','Wild+4','Wild+4','Wild+4']

import random

user_hand=[deck_red, deck_blue, deck_yellow, deck_green, wild_cards]

print("Your hand of cards:", user_hand )
```

Comment: Okay. You imported random, so, did you plan on using it? Read the module documentation?

Comment: Please read about a [mcve].... In other words - How do you get a random card from **one list**, that should help you do the same thing 7 (or more) times.

Comment: The specific implementation of this problem isn't going to help you solve it. Try breaking it down and solve for a single list first, then expand the problem (like @cricket_007 suggested)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to create a list called cards, which contains all cards. You can do this:

```
cards = []   # a list that cobtains all cards
# other card lists
cards.extend(deck_red, deck_green, deck_yellow, deck_blue, wild_cards)

random.shuffle(cards)  # shuffle the card list

hand = []

for i in range(0, 7):  # do the following 7 times
    hand.append(cards.pop()) # remove one card from cards list, add it to hands list
```

What this does is create a central 1D list of all cards,  no matter what type or color. Then, use random.shuffle  which essentially mixes all the elements in the cards list. Then I take seven cards ad add it to the hand list. Hope this helps.